# How to Add users to different group in Azure AD B2C during Registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to add users to different groups based on the url they are coming from. All users to be added under the same Azure B2C directory but under different group during registration.

Example:

1. www.admin.com -   User should go to  "Admin" group.
2. www.user.com - User should go to "Users" group.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use azure ad `dynamic user group` to do that, when you create a dynamic group with rules, the system evaluates all rules in a directory to see if the change would trigger any group adds or removes. If a user satisfies a rule on a group, they are added as a member of that group.

Reference - [**Dynamic membership rules for groups in Azure Active Directory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-dynamic-membership)

In your case, [`create the dynamic user group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-create-rule) `Admin`, to add the users to the `Admin` group, you just need to add the rule like `(user.userPrincipalName -match ".*admin.com*.")`, another one is the same logic.

[image]

After the system updated the group completely, it will appear like below.

[image]

Comment: Azure B2C does not support dynamic user groups. The option to create them is greyed out.